# How to convert index column to numeric?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe whose index row is string data type. I want it to be numeric and sorted:

```
  col1 col2
1  25   33
3  35  544
2  24   52
```

expected :

```
  col1 col2
1  25   33
2  24   52
3  35   544
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, convert and assign with `pd.to_numeric`.

```
df.index = pd.to_numeric(df.index, errors='coerce')
```

To sort the DataFrame by its index, call `df.sort_index`:

```
df.sort_index()

   col1  col2
1    25    33
2    24    52
3    35   544
```

You can specify `inplace=True` for the second command, if you want an inplace operation, or you can pass it down the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `astype` and `sort_index`

```
In [833]: df.index
Out[833]: Index([u'1', u'3', u'2'], dtype='object')

In [834]: df.index = df.index.astype(int)

In [837]: df = df.sort_index()

In [838]: df
Out[838]:
   col1  col2
1    25    33
2    24    52
3    35   544

In [839]: df.index
Out[839]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

**Or**, a single liner using `set_index`

```
In [851]: df.set_index(df.index.astype(int)).sort_index()
Out[851]:
   col1  col2
1    25    33
2    24    52
3    35   544
```